# how to clear memcached on centos?

Tags: memcached, centos

I have a centos server running memcached.  I use the spymemcached client to store cache key value pairs.

I need to clear all cache values and keys.

Do I do this on the client or server side?

I have tried the telnet method to flush_all

I have tried on the spymemcached side:

flush();

Neither of these clear the cache.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What is the response from telnet when you issue the flush_all command?

Comment: how is it possible one can flush the cache without logging in?  Wouldn't anyone be able to flush anyone's cache?

Comment: You only have to "log in" if you ar using sasl authentication. Also, memcached is supposed to be used behind a firewall so you shouldn't have to worry about someone else flushing your cache. If you are on an open port though then this is a potential security vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flush();` just invalidates all of the items in the memcached cache. You might need to restart the memcached server to clear the cache. Technically you are safe with go `flush();` memcached will use allocated memory when ever it needs.